# Is there a way to create a button (or div) with a border that has a gradient and has rounded corners?

Tags: css, border, css-shapes, linear-gradients

This is what it should look like:

[image]

**Attempts so far:**

1. Using a gradient background plus an inner element to cover it and leave just an outer "border". The **background is obviously not transparent**.

```css
body {
  background: #242424;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease-in-out,.2s,color;
}
a:hover {
  color: #DDD;
}

.nested {
  display: block;
  max-width: 20em;
  padding: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00ff00 0%, #00e5ff 100%);
}
.nested span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background: #242424;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
.nested span p {
  padding: 0 2em;
  margin: 0;
}

.pseudo {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  background: #242424;
}
.pseudo:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00ff00 0%, #00e5ff 100%);
  border-radius: 2em;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Gradient + Border Radius</h1>
    <a class="nested"><span><p>ANOTHER ONE</p></span></a>
    <a class="pseudo">AND ANOTHER ONE</a>
</div>
```

2. Using `border-image`. The **corners are not rounded**.

```css
body {
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns2015.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/ignasi_pattern_s.png);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #00aeef 0%, #7cc578 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  margin: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease-in-out,.2s,color;
}
a:hover {
  color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Gradient + [non working] Border Radius</h1>
    <a href="#">CLICK ME </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't use `border-image` on an element with `border-radius` because [as per specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-clipping), only the background of the element is clipped based on border radius and not the `border-image`. So the image would always be a rectangle (or square).

If the need is for a transparent center portion (or a transparent content area) then the best bet is to use SVG. SVG's stroke can take even a gradient as value and so it can produce a rounded shape whose border is a gradient and center portion is transparent.

The `path` used for creating the shape is simple and you can read more about path commands [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

```css
.border-with-grad {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}
.border-with-grad svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.border-with-grad path {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: url(#border-gradient);
  stroke-width: 4;
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;  
}
```

```html
<div class='border-with-grad'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 250 100'>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id='border-gradient' gradientUnits='objectBoundingBox' gradientTransform='rotate(5 0.5 0.5)'>
        <stop offset='0%' stop-color='rgb(248,244,135)' />
        <stop offset='25%' stop-color='rgb(248,244,135)' />
        <stop offset='75%' stop-color='rgb(53,176,182)' />
        <stop offset='100%' stop-color='rgb(53,176,182)' />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path d='M50,95 a45,45 0 0,1 0,-90 h150 a45,45 0 1,1 0,90 h-150' />
  </svg>
  CLICK HERE
</div>
```

---

With CSS, we can use `mask-image` to make the center portion as transparent but its browser support is very poor. At present only webkit powered browsers support this property. Another way would be to make use of `clip-path` but that is no-go if you need to support IE and Firefox (Firefox supports SVG clip paths only).

Answer (score 3):

If you need full browser support, And you want the inner part to be transparent, and you want a CSS only solution ... you can not use a gradient. You need to fake it whit shadows

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}  

.test:after  {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  
  width: calc(100% - 10px);  
  height: calc(100% - 10px);  
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: -20px 0px 10px 5px rgba(250, 250, 20, 1),
               20px 0px 10px 10px rgba( 20, 250, 200, 1);
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, black, darkgrey);
}
```

```html
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```